# Dynamic footer link based on current url

Tags: routes, uri, path-aliases

I've got a link to the mobile version of my site in the footer, but I need this link to be dynamic based off the page that the user is currently on.

Shown below are the options I have for the link.

[image]

Under the path there is this help text

`The path for this menu link. This can be an internal Drupal path such as node/add or an external URL such as http://drupal.org. Enter <front> to link to the front page.`

What I need is similar to the ability to use `<front>` to signify the homepage. I'd like to be able to use something like `http://m.example.com/<node>` so that this link will always go to the mobile version of the page that I'm currently on.

Is this possible? Or is what I want to do more complex than just using a keyword for the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default menu system won't let you do that...but if you install the [Menu Token](https://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module you should be able to use a path similar to the following to get what you need:

```
http://m.example.com/[current-page:url]
```

Comment: Perfect, does exactly what I need. I ended up using `[current-page:url:relative]` to get what I wanted. Many Thanks